# Suppose $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}, f'(x)=m$. Prove $f(x)=mx+b$ for some $b$ without the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

I'm trying to prove this assertion for arbitrary $f\colon U\subseteq E\to F$ where $U$ is an open in $E$ and $E,F$ are Banach spaces. In order to get some intuition, I tried proving it for the case $U,E,F=\mathbb{R}$ but can't think of a way that doesn't involve the fundamental theorem of calculus. I'm looking for hints for the following:

Let $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function and assume that there is a $m\in \mathbb{R}$ such that for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $f'(x)=m$. Show that there is a $b\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=mx+b$.

The restriction being: no FTC.

Comment: Well, do you know how to use the Mean Value Theorem to show that $F'(x)=0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$ implies $F(x)$ is constant?  If so, apply that to $F(x)=f(x)-mx$.

Comment: @lulu Nice, this can easily be generalized to arbitrary Banach spaces through the Finite Increase Theorem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The task can be reduced to real valued functions of one real  variable.
Let $f:U\to F$ be differentiable at every point of $U$ and $f'(x)\equiv M,$ where $M\in B(X,Y).$ With no loss of generality we may assume that $U$ is a ball centered at $0.$ Fix $0\neq a\in U$ and $\varphi\in F_{\mathbb{R}}^*.$ By assumptions we have
$${\|f(v+u)-f(v)-Mu\|\over \|u\|}\underset{u\to 0}{\longrightarrow} 0,\quad v\in U$$ Thus for   $t,h\in \mathbb{R}$ and $0\le t<1+\delta$ we get ($v=ta,$ $u=ha$)
$${|\varphi(f(ta+ha))-\varphi (f(ta))-h\varphi (Ma)|\over |h|}\underset{h\to 0}{\longrightarrow} 0$$
This implies that the function $g(t)=\varphi(f(ta))$ is differentiable for $0<t<1+\delta$ and $g'(t)\equiv \varphi(Ma).$  Hence $$\varphi(f(ta))=g(t)=\varphi(Ma)t+g(0)\\=\varphi(Ma)t+\varphi(f(0))=\varphi(tMa+f(0))$$
Therefore
$f(ta)=tMa+f(0).$ For $t=1$  we get
$f(a)=Ma+f(0).$